# CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread after await

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app with an ICommand that looks like this:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Consultant> Consultants { get; set; }

public Consultant Selected { get; set; }

public ICommand InsertCommand => this.insertCommand ?? (this.insertCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
{
    string result = await InsertAsync(this.Selected.Name, this.Selected.ID);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        this.Consultants.Remove(this.Consultants.Single(i => i == this.Selected));
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        this.dialogService.ShowMessage(result, "Add Consultant");
    }
}));
```

The issue is that the line `this.Consultants.Remove(this.Consultants.Single(i => i == this.Selected));` is throwing the exception `CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread`.

What I'm confused about is that even if I take out all other code (i.e. the `await` line before), it still throws this error. Why is is running a different thread (i.e. non-UI/main) in that situation?

I don't recall having to do that for other similar commands, but perhaps the way I'm removing the record from `Consultants` is different which causes the problem.

I could wrap that line in a `Dispatcher.Invoke`, but I'm concerned this is masking a different problem in my code/logic.

Comment: You may want to use an [ICommand implementation that supports async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47671774/1136211). Also search for AsyncRelayCommand.

Comment: If you're binding Selected can't you just call remove(selected)? Is it not the same object? I recommend the mvvm community toolkit. Would save you repeated code. Failing that, null coalescing ??= On your command.

Comment: @Andy You're absolutely right. No idea why I overcomplicated it there. This is using mvvmlight - it does need migrating to Community Toolkit, but for various reasons that not super simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of my issue. In my `LoadData` method, the collection `this.Consultants` was being set from a `Task.Run` like this:

```cs
Task tsk = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return this.GetConsultantsAsync(false);
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsCompleted)
    {
        this.Consultants = t.Result;
    }
});
```

It is done this way, rather than simply doing `this.Consultants = await this.GetConsultantsAsync(false);` because this method is calling a couple of other methods in the same way, and it awaits them all later (e.g. `await Task.WhenAll(tsk, tsk2, tsk3);`), so we only need to wait for the slowest one.

However, doing it this way meant that the collection was being set on a thread pool thread, rather than the main thread, which was then being used later in my `InsertCommand`, as I had expected. So I have left the `InsertCommand` as it is, and instead changed the loading method to this:

```cs
Task tsk = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return this.GetConsultantsAsync(false);
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsCompleted)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            this.Consultants = t.Result;
        });
    }
});
```

An alternative would be to drop the `ContinueWith` part and instead do:

```cs
Task<ObservableCollection> tskConsultants = this.GetConsultantsAsync(false);

//Other tasks

this.Consultants = await tskConsultants;

//Alternative, using Task.WhenAll
await Task.WhenAll(tskConsultants) //if you have more than 1 task to await, list them here

this.Consultants = tsk.Consultants.Result;
```

Comment: When GetConsultantsAsync is already async, it makes no sense at all to wrap it in a Task.Run call. You would simply write `Consultants = await GetConsultantsAsync(false);`

Comment: It makes plenty of sense in context, which isn't provided in this answer because it's not strictly relevant. This method it calls a couple of other async methods to load different data, and it then does an `await Task.WhenAll()` on those tasks. This way we load in the shortest possible time, rather than awaiting one after the other, which would be slower.

Comment: That should become more obvious in the answer. Right now it is just an example of something you shouldn't be doing. It would also benefit from an explanation of the ContinueWith calls, where you would usually just have one or more awaits. IMO this is at best useless for anybody else and bears a risk of misleading others.

Comment: Shouldn't be doing according to who? Using `Task.Run` with `ContinueWith` is a perfectly reasonable way to use an async function if you don't want to await immediately, and also do something with the result. My question was to do with the thread which created the collection not being the expected one. This answer explains why that was, and how to resolve it, when using this approach. Whether or not someone should use this approach depends entirely on their context, which is for them to decide.

Comment: But you are aware that (at least in the example in this post) you could have written `var tsk = GetConsultantsAsync(false).ContinueWith(t => ...);`?

Comment: Yes. I have just added alternative/simplified options to the answer. I don't recall why we were using `Task.Run` instead of just assigning the task from the method directly, but it might be something which has changed with previous refactors and is no longer required. I'll need to test.